# Kafka Listener : Poll interval : How to schedule kafka consumer poll() with 15 min interval

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

How can I schedule poll() interval for 15 min in Kafka listener?

My sample code for 5 min poll interval works fine but I have a requirement for schedule poll() interval with 15 min diff.

```
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    private final String SERVERS = "localhost:9092";

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, SERVERS);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer-group");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "5000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 900000); 
                return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(60000l); 
    return factory;
    }

 @KafkaListener(id = "batch-listener", topics = TOPIC_01, group =
       "test-consumer-group", 
              containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")//groupId = "test-consumer-group", 
         public void messageListener(List<String> messages) {
          log.info("Recieved {} messages", messages.size());
             messages.forEach(message ->
                     log.info("MessageListener recieved message : {}", message));   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is not clear

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 300000);
```

change it to 900000 if you need that much time to process your 10 records.

If you mean you only want to fetch records every 15 minutes, use

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000000);
```

and

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(900000);
```

Comment: my requirement is to pull 5000 records for each consumer poll() which should happen every 15 min, sir.

Comment: MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG if I add 900000=15 min fetch itself not happening. somewhere it's just rebalancing.

Comment: `>my requirement is to pull 5000 records for each consumer poll() which should happen every 15 min, sir.` There's no way to do that reliably with a message-driven approach; you should consider using a `KafkaConsumer` directly and poll it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000000); 
 factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(900000);

Poll() of messages as a batch is working as expected.

thank you @Gary